# Order of Factor Group of Direct Product

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to show that $G = (Z \oplus Z)/\langle(2,2)\rangle$ has infinite order (size).

Can I just say that $\forall (a,b)\langle(2,2)\rangle \in G$, we can consider $(a+1,b+1)\rangle(2,2)\rangle\in G$?

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing: what is $(a,b)\langle(2,2)\rangle$ ? Did you mean the coset of $(a,b)$? Presumably, but since additive notation is in use, that coset is denoted by $(a,b)+\langle(2,2)\rangle$.

Comment: Provided my guess in the comment above is correct the answer is `No'. That argument does not show anything. You need to show that there are infinitely many different cosets of $\langle(2,2)\rangle$. And we always have $(a,b)+\langle(2,2)\rangle=(a+2,b+2)+\langle(2,2)\rangle$. This means that by adding $(1,1)$ to the coset representatives simply alternates between two cosets, and thus only give two distinct elements of $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that the cosets $(m,0)+\langle(2,2)\rangle, m\in\Bbb{Z},$ are all distinct.